# How to check if querybuilder (sql) has "GroupBy" part

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

how to check if doctrine querybuilder has groupby part? For me is important only group by on end of sql, not in inner-select...

I must set other reaction in script for sql with groupby and without groupby. It is in my own datagrid, so the sql is create dynamicly...

I look for something like ->hasGroupBy() or ->partExists('groupBy')...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`getQueryPart`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.7/Doctrine/DBAL/Query/QueryBuilder.html#method_getQueryPart) to check if there are any `groupBy` parts in your query, e.g.

```
$groupByParts = $queryBuilder->getQueryPart('groupBy');

if ($groupByParts) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->queryBuilder->getQueryPart('groupBy')
```